# React facebook login is not working some browser?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to apply the react-facebook-login package in my project. But I am getting some problems with the package implementation. It is **not working in some browsers like Microsoft edge and google chrome**. But it is working in Mozilla firefox and some mobile browser.

Actually, it is **not opening a pop-up in those browsers**. I am trying to allow popup and redirect, But not working.

Can anyone give a possible problem and solutions about this?

**Updated**

```
import FacebookLogin from "react-facebook-login/dist/facebook-login-render-props";

<FacebookLogin
    appId = { process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FACEBOOK_APP_ID as string }
    autoLoad = { false}
    fields = "name,email,picture"
    callback = { responseFacebook }
    onClick = {() => console.log("clicked")}
    render = {(renderProps: any) => (
        <ButtonBase sx={styles.FacebookButton} onClick={renderProps.onClick} disabled={faLoading}>
            <Icon icon="bi:facebook" />
            Continue with Facebook
            {faLoading &&
                <CircularProgress size={16} sx={{ color: "background.default", ml: "10px", mb: "-2px" }} />
            }
        </ButtonBase>
    )}
/>
```

Comment: Please post a code snippet or some outputs!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.